# Two DataGridViews with the same content. Can I have the same column names?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using 2 DataGridViews on 2 tabs on the same form, and they contain the same information, but are used in 2 different ways. Trust me, it makes sense in this situation. :)

When I create the DataGridViews, C# seems to be telling me that I need to give the **columns** unique names even though they are in different tables.

Is there a way around this?  It seems to me to be completely unnecessary from a logic perspective, and will make for messy code if I have to have two functions that will populate two tables with the same values.  It would be great if I could use the same function and just pass in the target DataGridView as an argument. I am hoping that I am just missing something obvious.

Any advice ... or logical explanation?

Comment: The column objects have to have unique names but they can have the same title/header shown to the user.  There is no need for you to manually create them though - the DGV will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... you have confirmed my "fear".  Any idea WHY they need to be different?  It just seems like a completely unnecessary constraint.  My brain doesn't like illogical restrictions. :)

Comment: It's not clear what has to be different?  How are these two data grids related?

Comment: Why do they need to be anything other than Column1, Column2, Column3...?  You dont typically reference them directly as objects once they have been created and added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create the columns using designer, then their names should be unique like any other component.

The reason is because designer generates member fields for columns based on their name and you cannot have two fields with the same name.

If you don't create the columns using designer and just create them using code, or by setting [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to `true`, then there is no restriction as the columns just will be added to the `DataGridView` without having fields in form.

FYI, In addition to find columns by name, you can find them by `Index` as well.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not. Because every tool in the form has a one unique id name to call it .So every "dataGridView" , and every column has it's unique id .

Try using one or two "groupBox"s or "panel"s . To put each "dataGridView" Separately in its block .